# Объединить несколько строк в одну строку в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм pandas, у которого искомые значения указаны в индексе.
Как можно объединить строки получив сумму значений столбцов.
Например: исходный датафрейм

```
               column1    column2    column3    columnN
200100000001    1        20         1              3
200100000009    1        55         1              3
200100000004    1        30         2              12
200100000005    1        50         3              4
```

из исходного датафрейма ищу значения по индексу из списка

```
listgroup = [some list]
df[df.index.isin([200100000004,200100000005])]
```

и хочу получить следующий результат:

```
                           column1    column2    column3    columnN
200100000004,200100000005   2        80         5              16
```

количество столбцов, и их наименования заранее не известны

Comment: df[df.index.isin([200100000004,200100000005])].sum() ?

Comment: да, но .sum(axis=1) формирует новое значение для суммы столбцов, то бишь не 2 80 5 16, а 103

Comment: а зачем вам axis=1, если вам нужно axis=0?

Comment: согласен, точно, спасибо